# Join list of tuples?

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples that looks like:

```
tup_a = [('vs', 'UT Martin'), ('@', 'Purdue'), ('vs', '#6 Houston'), ('vs', 'Miami (OH)')]
```

How can I get something like this:

```
tup_b = [('vs UT Martin'), ('@ Purdue'), ('vs #6 Houston'), ('vs Miami (OH)')]
```

Or even this as I don't really need it in tuple form at all:

```
list_a = ['vs UT Martin', '@ Purdue', 'vs #6 Houston', 'vs Miami (OH)']
```

I've been playing with `.join` but I also remember that Tuples are immutable so i'm a bit confused on how to go about this.

Comment: `[" ".join(i) for i in tup(a)]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
 [(" ".join(x),)  for x in tup_a]
```

Note that the trailing `,` is not an error, it's perfectly acceptable for a tuple to have a trailing `,` if you don't want it as a tuple after all

```
 [" ".join(x)  for x in tup_a]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
tup_a = [('vs', 'UT Martin'), ('@', 'Purdue'), ('vs', '#6 Houston'), ('vs', 'Miami (OH)')]

l = [str(x)+' '+str(y) for x,y in tup_a]
print l
# ['vs UT Martin', '@ Purdue', 'vs #6 Houston', 'vs Miami (OH)']
```

Using list comprehension (for second form)

Answer (score 2):

```
[" ".join(aa) for aa in tup_a]
```

will result in

```
['vs UT Martin', '@ Purdue', 'vs #6 Houston', 'vs Miami (OH)']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try [map](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map):

```
map(" ".join, tup_a)
```

With your data:

```
>>> tup_a = [('vs', 'UT Martin'), ('@', 'Purdue'), ('vs', '#6 Houston'), ('vs', 'Miami (OH)')]
>>> map(" ".join, tup_a)
['vs UT Martin', '@ Purdue', 'vs #6 Houston', 'vs Miami (OH)']
```

I usually prefer *list comprehension* to *map*, but this is really perfect job for mapping a list!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
tup_a = [('vs', 'UT Martin'), ('@', 'Purdue'), ('vs', '#6 Houston'), ('vs', 'Miami (OH)')]

new_tup = [(' '.join(i)) for i in tup_a]
```

Answer (score -1):

You could just use the built-in list function,

```
list(" ".join(item) for item in tup_a)
```

Comment: would you please explain the reason for this downvote??.. It may help me next time, if I did anything wrong..

Comment: The code gives the same output as required, I've tried it.

Comment: Code only answers usually attract downvotes; consider adding some explanation, references to documentation, etc.

Comment: Sorry, I'd try to do the same, from now on.